# Paste Code in Microsoft Visual Studio has no Syntax Color highlighting

Tags: c++, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

I have a problem when I copy code around in my solution in Microsoft Visual Studio (newest version). The pasted code doesn't have color highlighting; it's just white.

[image: Screenshot]

As seen in the picture, the "string" in "std::string" should be green, and "Test" should be blue, but both are white.

However, as soon as I move my mouse over the line and then press Ctrl, the line gets updated and has the correct colors afterward.

[image: Updated Screenshot]

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Have you installed any plugins? Try resetting Visual Studios settings. (Tools -> Import and Export -> Reset all settings)

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT I dont have any plugins installed at all. I just tried to reset all settings. all it changes is that the font is now bigger/different, but the problem is still there: [Picture](https://i.imgur.com/AOCJWuL.png)

Comment: I've seen similar issues before, typically when Intellisense is very busy due to a very large project. Normally, either editing said lines or just waiting long enough will "fix" it.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your problem.

[image]

Since it is related to product problem, please report to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp) and post link here so that we can vote the thread.